# Reverse engineer wrong character encoding

Tags: java, postgresql, character-encoding

Our system (Java) reads from another server first names and last names (in Korean).  Almost all are saved correctly into our PostgreSql database except for a few. Everything (Java request, webpage and db) is set to UTF-8. Example, the text in db is as follows:

```
+------------------+-----------+
| first_name       | last_name |
+------------------+-----------+    
| ì\u008B í\u0098¸ | ì\u009C   |
+------------------+-----------+
|ì\u008B¼ì\u0098©  | ìµ\u009C  |
+------------------+-----------+
```

**The question:** Is there a way to reverse engineer what these values should have been?

(We don't have access to the other system, other than, the api call to it)

Comment: If the data are written to the database by the JDBC driver, they must have been wrong before they got to the JDBC driver.

Answer (score 0):

The data was originally encoded in UTF8, but was read by something assuming it was in [Latin-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1#Code_page_layout).

For example, [최](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+CD5C) in UTF8 is `0xEC` `0xB5` `0x9C`.

Interpreted as Latin-1, `0xEC` is `ì`, `0xB5` is `µ`, and `0x9C` (although technically undefined), is usually mapped to the [U+009C control character](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/009c/index.htm).

So, it looks like the `ìµ\u009C` string in your database was originally 최.

As long as these character sequences made it to Postgres intact, without being further mangled by something else along the way, then you should be able to convert them back:

```
select convert_from(convert_to(E'ìµ\u009C', 'LATIN1'), 'UTF8')
```

Some of the strings in your example (`'ì\u008B '` and `'ì\u009C'`) don't appear to correspond to valid UTF8 byte sequences, but it's possible that they're still valid in your database, and that some control characters were lost in the copy-paste.